# For loop for array in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: oop, smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to make an array with random numbers (just 0 or 1), but when I run it, it just prints this:  End of statement list encountered ->

This is my code:

```
GenList
 | lista |
  lista := Array new: 31.
  1 to: 30 do: [ :i | lista at: i put: 2 atRandom - 1]
  ^lista
```

What can I do?

Comment: You are missing dot (end of statement) after the 4th line.

Comment: Also no point in constructing array... you can do `^ (1 to: 30) collect: [ :i | 2 atRandom - 1]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Some interesting things to consider:

---

*1. The method selector doesn't start with a lowercase letter*

---

It is a tradition for selectors to start with a lowercase letter. In this sense, `genLista` would be more correct than `GenLista`.

---

*2. The method selector includes the abbreviated word 'gen'*

---

For instance, `genLista` could be renamed to `genereLista` o `listaAlAzar` (if you decide to use Spanish)

---

*3. The `Array` named `lista` has 31 elements, not 30*

---

The result of `Array new: 31` is an array of 31 elements. However, the code below it only fills 30 of them, leaving the last one uninitialized (i.e., `nil`). Possible solution: `lista := Array new: 30`.

---

*4. A dot is missing causing a compilation error*

---

The code

```
  1 to: 30 do: [ :i | lista at: i put: 2 atRandom - 1]
  ^lista
```

does not compile because there is no dot indicating the separation between the two sentences. Note that the error happens at compilation time (i.e., when you save the method) because the return token `^` must start a statement (i.e., it cannot be inlined inside a statement).

There are other cases where a missing dot will not prevent the code from compiling. Instead, an error will happen at runtime. Here is a (typical) example:

```
1 to: 10 do: [:i | self somethingWith: i]     "<- missing dot here"
self somethingElse
```

the missing dot will generate the runtime error `self not understood by block`.

---

*5. There is a more expressive way of generating 0s and 1s at random*

---

The calculation `2 atRandom - 1` is ok. However, it forces the reader to mentally do the math. A better way to reveal your intention would have been

```
#(0 1) atRandom
```

---

*6. When playing with random numbers don't forget to save the seed*

---

While it is ok to use `atRandom`, such a practice should only be used with "toy" code. If you are developing a system or a library, the recommended practice is to save the seed somewhere before generating any random data. This will allow you to reproduce the generation of random quantities later on for the sake of debugging or confirmation. (Note however, that this will not suffice for making your program deterministically reproducible because unordered (e.g. hashed) collections could form differently in successive executions.)