# If statements(no returns) in Pharo Smalltalk for flatten list

Tags: oop, if-statement, smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to make a list(30) of lists (30). 
I have this:

```
#(#(a a a) nil nil #(b) #(c) #(d) nil nil nil #(e e) nil #(f f) nil #(g) 
  #(h) nil nil nil #(i  i) nil nil nil #(j) nil nil nil nil nil 
  #(k) #(l l l)
```

And I want to do a program that turns that into just a list like this:

```
 #(a a a b c d e e f f g hi i j k l l l)
```

My code is this:

```
ToList: lista
    | retorno y z |
    retorno := Array new: 30.
    y := 1.
    (1 to: lista size)
        do: [ :i | 
            z := 0.
            (lista at: i) isNil
            ifFalse: 
            (1 to: (lista at: i) size do: [ :j | retorno at: (y + z) put: ((lista at: i) at: j )
                y:= y+1.
                z:= z +1.]
            )].
        ^retorno
```

I think there are some problems with the if-statements, because there's no return. I don't know what to do, because it works without the `y:= y+1.`, but it keeps some nil spaces.

Please, help me!

Comment: `flatCollect` can take care of this in a single method call

Comment: You should give your variables more descriptive names, so the code is easier to understand. i could be outerIndex, y could be outputIndex, j could be innerIndex, and z... well, whatever your intention for z is.

Comment: In addition to Alexander's hint if you should code a kind of flatCollect yourself: Consider to not access collection elements by index, but directly. Instead of `1 to: list size do: [:index | "do something with" (list at: index)]` simply write `list do: [:each | "do something with" each]`. For the output you could use an OrderedCollection instead of an Array and simply use `add:` to append elements. You could also have a look at the message `gather:` understood by all collections in Squeak/Pharo.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Have you read @Leandro's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913888/983430) to your question where you forgot a full stop? There are several good points there that you seem not to have learned, in particular about method names starting with lowercase and about explicit naming (a hallmark of Smalltalk). Given that you're asking your question in English, could you please make the effort of translating words in the example code as a courtesy? 2) If this is about homework (which is fine), please say so and [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/983430).

Answer (score 4):

There are two syntax errors in your code:

1. The arguments of `ifTrue:`, `ifFalse:`, etc., are block and blocks in Smalltalk are expressions enclosed in squared brackets, not parenthesis. In your case you should write

   ```
   (lista at: i) isNil
     ifFalse: 
       [1 to: (lista at: i               "<- [ not ("
   ```

   and close with

   ```
           z:= z +1.]
       ]].                               "<- ]] not )]."
   ```
2. There is a dot missing at the end of the long line:

   ```
   .... put: ((lista at: i) at: j)          "<- dot missing"
           y:= y+1.
           z:= z +1.
   ```

After fixing these two issues you should be able to run the code to see whether it works as expected (or debug it if not.) But that is another story...

---

**ADDENDUM**

There is also something suspicious here.

In Smalltalk we use single quotes to delimit literal strings (`'Hello world'`) and the dollar sign in front of literal characters, like in `$a`.

In addition, we have literal arrays, which are composed of other literals and enclosed between `#(` and `)`, as in `#('a' $a)`.

Now, in your code you have written expressions such as `#(a a a)`, which do not conform to the formats we've just seen. So, what does this mean? More precisely, how would the Smalltalk compiler interprete this notation? The answer is that it will assume that you meant:

```
#(#a #a #a)
```

i.e., an array of `Symbols`, and that you didn't want to write so many `#`s. So, in your exercise, you should think whether you actually wanted characters `#($a $a $a)`, strings `#('a' 'a' 'a')` or symbols `#(#a #a #a)`.

The same goes for other strings. For example, `#(abc de)` will get compiled as `#(#abc #de)`...

... mmm...

But wait a minute. If this is so, why then `#(#(a a a) nil)` doesn't get compiled as `#(#(a a a) #nil)`? Well, because the compiler makes an exception with `nil`, `true` and `false`... uff!

Also note that in some dialects of Smalltalk the compiler will interprete `#((a a a))` as `#(#(a a a))` so you don't have to type that many pound signs...

**Summarizing**. If you choose to save some pounds in literal arrays, be consistent and write `#((a a a))` rather than `#(#(a a a))`. Otherwise be completeley explicit and write `#(#(#a #a #a))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it as:

```
flattenArray: anArray
  | ws |

  ws = WriteStream on: (Array new).
  anArray do: [:subArr| : 
                     subArr notNil ifTrue: [
                        subArr do: [ :el | ws nextPut: el ]]].
  ^ws contents.
```

There are 2 general remarks, it is rarely necessary to access collection elements by index, if you are doing it, stop, and think if there are more elegant methods available. Second WriteStreams are handy when you want to collect series of results.